# On proving $(f^{-1})'(b) = \frac{1}{f'(a)}. $ where $b = f(a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, proof-writing

Could somebody kindly provide a proof or a reference to a proof of this fact:

> Let $ I $ be an open interval, and suppose that $ f: I \to \mathbb{R} $ is one-to-one and continuous on $ I $. If $ f $ is differentiable at $ a \in I $ and $ f'(a) \neq 0 $, then $ f^{-1}: f[I] \to I $ is differentiable at $ b = f(a) $ and
>   $$
> (f^{-1})'(b) = \frac{1}{f'(a)}.
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rather well known theorem about the derivative of an inverse function. Let us put $\;g:=f^{-1}\;$ , for simplicity, and observe that both

$$\begin{cases}\;y\to b\implies& \;\;(y=)\;\color{red}{f(x)\to f(a)}\;(=b)\\{}\\f(x)\to f(a)\implies&\;\; (g(f(x))=)\;\color{red}{x\to a}\;(=g(f(a)))\end{cases} \;\;\;\text{(why?)}$$ , so:

$$(f^{-1})'(b)=g'(b):=\lim_{y\to b}\frac{g(y)-g(b)}{y-b}=\lim_{y\to b\implies f(x)\to f(a)}\frac{g(y)-g(b)}{f(x)-f(a)}=$$

$$=\lim_{f(x)\to f(a)\implies x\to a}\frac{x- a}{f(x)- f(a)}=\frac1{f'(a)}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the chain rule $$(f^{-1} \circ f )(x) = x \implies (f^{-1} \circ f ) ' (x) = 1 \implies (f^{-1})'(f(x)) f'(x) = 1$$

Apply it at $a$.

Conversely, if $f'(a) \neq 0$ then any sequence of points $y_n = f(x_n) \in Y - \{b\}$ with $\lim y_n = b$ the continuity of $g$ at $b$ yields $\lim x_n = a$ then

$$\begin{align}g'(b) = \lim \frac{g(y_n) - g(b)}{y_n - b} &= \lim \left[\frac{y_n - b}{g(y_n) - g(b)}\right]^{-1} \\&=\lim \left[\frac{f(x_n) - f(a)}{x_n - a}\right]^{-1}\\&=\frac{1}{f'(a)} \end{align}$$

Then you show

> $g = f^{-1}$ is differentiable if, and only if, $f'(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: This is nice... **when** we already know $\;\left(f^{-1}\right)'\;$ exists, otherwise the second implication, using the chain rule, is unjustified.

Comment: This is an equivalence. But sure you're correct.

Comment: Seriously that this answer is not useful?

Comment: Of course it is, yet the OP's question **also** required to prove the inverse function's derivative exists at $\;b\;$, a proof which your original answer didn't included. With the last edit it already includes it.